# T-SQL slow query tuning options?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016. I am running the following update query:

```
update a set a.[Project Definition]=b.[Project] FROM [Table1] a 
inner join [Table2] b 
on dbo.fReplace(a.[Project Definition]) = dbo.fReplace(b. 
[PROJECT #]) 
and a.[Project Definition] <>'' 
and difference(a.[Project Description],b.[Project Name])>=3
```

Where [fReplace] is defined as follows (it just strips all non-numeric characters from a field):

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fReplace](@strtext varchar(2000))
returns varchar(2000)
as
begin
declare @i int = 32, @rplc varchar(1) = '';
while @i < 256
begin
    if (@i < 48 or @i > 57) and CHARINDEX(char(@i),@strtext) > 0
    begin
        --° #176 ~ 0   --¹ #185 ~ 1   --² #178 ~ 2   --³ #179 ~ 3
        set @rplc = case @i
        when 176 then '0'
        when 185 then '1'
        when 178 then '2'
        when 179 then '3'
        else '' end;

        set @strtext = REPLACE(@strtext,CHAR(@i),@rplc);
    end

    set @i = @i + 1;
end
return ltrim(rtrim(@strtext));
end
```

The query runs very slow... Any way to speed it up?
Note that I added indexes by the fields above already.

Regards,
M.R.

Comment: Any Chance you can strip out the characters in code ?

Comment: Do you mean adding new columns with stripped codes and rewrite the query? yes, I could do that eventually...

Comment: But only if there is no other solution

Comment: Indexing isn't going to help much here. You have a scalar function with a loop in it. This function has to execute for every single row in the table to determine if it would be a match or not. You have the same problem again in your where clause.

Comment: @M.R. No, I mean whatever application that calls your stored proc needs to strip the codes. Your function is killing you and there isnt a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functions in join conditions is probably what's causing your slowness as it creates a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) condition.  SQL Server can't perform your JOIN as a set operation, rather it must use loops.  If you run your query and have it return the execution plan you will most likely see that.

Adding columns to your table to hold the return values of the function would help speed up your JOIN.

Comment: Yes, I can understand this. I was hoping there is another way, maybe SQL Server 2016-2017 specific

Comment: No, there's no way around it.  The function has to be called for each row in the table at some point.  You can either do that processing in your query or during some other scheduled update.  If you do it in your query you will need to expect it to be slow, depending on how many rows you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes won't help because you're not looking for the values, you're looking for the function result.  This has to do a table scan on both tables and run the function for each row.  If you could create a compute column in each table and create an index on that it should speed up:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD ComputeId AS (dbo.fReplace([Project Definition]))

CREATE INDEX Table1_ComputedIndex ON Table1 (ComputeId)
```

Comment: Cannot add the index though because IsPersisted=No